# Simple proof that there is no isomorphism between any two of $ Aut(\hat{C}) $(Riemann Sphere),$ Aut(H^+) $(upper half plane) and $ Aut(C) $

Tags: complex-analysis

Referring the groups of automorphisms (holomorphic bijections) of the respective domains.

This is a homework problem. Is a basic course, so sophisticated answers may not be of help (it has a simple solution according to my teacher).  Also, it looks like an Algebra problem, but I’ve been assured that there is a solution within complex analysis, so if anyone can give a non algebraic proof, it will be appreciated. I tried constructing a conformal mapping (between two of the domains) using a supposed isomorphism, also calculate the unit roots (of second degree, and some of higher degree) in each of the groups, and a couple ideas more, but with no luck. 
Thanks in advance for your help (and sorry about my poor English).

Edit:The question was edited to avoid sophisticated algebraic answers.  Please, just use the very basic of algebra in your solution. Is a complex analysis exercise! (of course, if you just want to share a sohpisticated answer that can help other users, welcome.)

Comment: What do you mean by $\hat C$?

Comment: @mrf, sorry, I thought it was a standar notation. The complete Riemann esphere, so $Aut(\hat C)$ are the Mobius transformations.

Comment: If you want to prove that the groups are pairwise _abstractly_ non-isomorphic (as opposed to, say, showing that restriction does not give an isomorphism $\operatorname{Aut}(\hat {\mathbb{C}}) \to \operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{C}))$, then I think you're not going to have much luck staying inside complex analysis and not using any algebra.

Comment: @anomaly, I had the same impresion since the first minute I tried to solve it, but I want to think the professor is not just torturing me. You think there is a more simple solution (that the one given by Mosher) using algebra?

Comment: Mosher's solution is the one I'd use. More generally, the first group is solvable (in fact, it's the semidirect product of two copies of $\mathbb{R}$), while the second two contain a lot of large, badly-behaved subgroups by the Tits alternative. Distinguishing $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ from $PSL_2(\mathbb{C})$ as abstract, non-topological groups is a bit trickier; maybe the Galois group actions would be useful. The groups $PSL_2(k)$ are actually quite easy to work with and well-known, but the situation is tricky if you don't assume anything at all about them.

Answer (score 2):

$L(C)$ is solvable, the other two aren't.

${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, ${\rm PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ doesn't.

Comment: In fact, even the group of real numbers contains a subgroup isomorphic to $R^2$. What you mean is that $PSL(2,R)$ contains no subgroups which are topologically isomorphic to $R^2$. The correct proof that the groups in question are not isomorphic as abstract groups can be given using finite subgroups ($PSL(2,R)$ contains no simple finite subgroups, while $PSL(2,C)$ does). None of this is elementary, of course.

Comment: @studiosus: Ah yes, careless of me. Thanks for that correction.

Answer (score 2):

In $Aut(\mathbb{C})=L(\mathbb{C})$, the product of two elements of order $7$ cannot be of order $3$. In $Aut(H^+) \le Aut(\bar{\mathbb{C}})$ it can.

In the hyperbolic half plane model ($H^+$) take an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with angles $\frac{2\pi}7$. Let $a$ and $b$ be the rotations about $A$ and $B$, respectively, by angle $2\pi/7$. Then $a^{-1}b$ moves $ABC$ to $CAB$, so $a^{-1}b$ is of order $3$.

---

In $Aut(\bar{\mathbb{C}})$ there are two elements of order $2$ whose product also is of order $2$: just take three perpendicular diameters of the sphere and consider the reflections about them. For instance $z\mapsto -z$ and $z\mapsto \frac1z$ are of order 2, and their composition is $\frac{-1}z$.

$Aut(H^+)$ consists of oriented isometries of the half plane model and all elements of order 2 are reflections about points. If you take two reflections about two distinct points, say $A$ and $B$ then their product will be a translation on the line $AB$ which cannot be of order 2.